# What is the reference point of `drawImage()` in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

This is a question about the [`drawImage()`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp) function.

```
    var x = (i-j)*(img[0].height/2) + (ctx.canvas.width/2)-(img[0].width/2); 
    var y = (i+j)*(img[0].height/4);
    abposx = x + offset_x;
    abposy = y + offset_y;
    ctx.drawImage(img[0], abposx, abposy);
```

This code draws an image with its offset in a canvas. One thing I wanted to know was the "drawImage" ... does it place it by the left corner of the image to the position or its middle?

If it does use the left corner how can I change it so it places it based on the center of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas coordinate system starts at `(0,0)` in the top-left corner ([source](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html)).

So yes, `drawImage` will draw starting at the upper left corner.

You can draw using the center of the image by simply offsetting it by `width/2` and `height/2`.

So if you have some central point `p`,

`drawImage(image, p.x - image.width/2, p.y - image.height/2)`

is equivalent to drawing from the upper left hand corner.

Comment: what do you mean by a central point ? couldn't i offset the image by image's half width and height without the p ?

Comment: In this case, your central point `p` is comprised of `abposx` and `abposy`. I think you & I are actually saying the same thing. I just used a more general term where `p` is where on the canvas you'd like the center of the image to be.

Comment: so abposx - image.width/2 

is essentially offsetting it by "half the image's width same for height - so it centeres it that way? i think i get it :)

Comment: Yup! That's exactly what I meant.